# How do I get my existing Activity to display?

Tags: android, android-activity

How do I get my app to appear in on the screen after it has been replaced by some other screen/activity?  Some network event occurs and my application wants to reappear in the foreground (presumably in a polite manner).

I think I need to do something like:

contxt.startActivity(myActivity);

I don't want to create another instance of my app or cause it to restart, but I want it to appear.

Comment: Have you started an other activity ?

Comment: A polite manner would be to show a notification, which opens your required activity when clicked. I think that you're not allowed to start your activity from background without user interaction.

Comment: Have you read about the activities lifecycle? Check this: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ImplementingLifecycleCallbacks

Comment: Show some code, else we are just assuming.

Comment: Nahuel: I've looked at the lifecycle state diagram before, perhaps not that particular page.  That shows more of the 'how the activity gets events when state changes more than how to change your state.

Comment: ottle142: Agreed, a notification and a click would be appropriate when the phone is in use.  I was thinking of the phone being idle (screen turned off, perhaps even 'locked') And wanting a very quick route to seeing what is going on.  (I know the convention is that you need to do an unlock before displaying information.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

```
Intent intent = new Intent(contxt, myActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
contxt.startActivity(intent);
```

In your myActivity onNewIntent is called. I assume myActivity is the top activity in your app current stack